# Coreldraw importing from autocad incorrectly

Tags: image-editing, vector-graphics, autocad, coreldraw

Ok I have an odd issue. We use coreldraw to print to our laser cutter. (X3 usually but this happens in X5 as well). You can see the issue in the photos below. In autocad the squares are equidistant from the outer perimiter however after importing into corel the ones on the top are closer than the zones on the side. This leads to the kerf of the laser burning through on the top.

I have tried several different formats (DXF and DWG 2000 and 2004) and nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

EDIT: Here is a [copy of the dwg.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36703262/superuser.dwg) I can get a coreldraw file if need be just let me know.

[image: Corel]
[image: Autocad]

Comment: Does it "scale" any other part of the image?

Comment: Ive never noticed this before because it is a lot finer detail than I normally try to cut on the laser. It could have been doing this on everything and I would not have noticed.

As for messing with any other dimensions I don't have a clue how to measure stuff in corel to find out. This just happens to be something I can visually look at and see.

Comment: You could try [DXFTool](http://www.coreldrawtools.com/) to export from Corel to dxf (commercial $59.95, 30 days trial version). I have no experience with this product.

Comment: I am confused as to how this would help me. I am not trying to go from corel to dwg/dxf. I am trying to go the opposite route.

Comment: Sorry - my confusion. I have tried your dwg in IrfanView and it displays as in autocad. So I believe that this is a problem of Corel and you should ask for help from their Support, or use another imaging product.

Answer (score 1):

Well after a bunch of messing around I have found that it has to do with lwpolylines. It seems that corel does not like them. If I explode it back to the original arcs and lines it imports perfectly.